# Hindi (localized) font not showing in windows form application on window xp

Tags: c#, windows, fonts

I have created windows desktop application with C#. I have used some Hindi font in that application. When i run app on Windows 7 or windows 8 then it is working fine but when I run application on windows xp it shows me an Boxes instead of the Hindi fonts.

I have included the fonts in the application .exe file also install the same fonts on target machines font folder but didn't worked.

How can I show the Hindi font on windows XP?
 Do I need to do some settings on windows XP system or need to to do any changes in my app for Window XP?

Please refer screenshot:

[image]

Thanks in advance. I am still not getting any answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try getting the platform the application is running on, and if it is Windows XP then change the font to something else?

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I am trying to create separate setup of application for windows xp but still not getting any solution for windows xp platform.